# Drools Expert 5.x: API call to get list of all current facts?

Tags: drools, fact

How do I list all the current inserted facts so that I can serialize them ? Kinda like running '(facts)' in a CLIPS session ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it...StatefulKnowledgeSession.getObjects()